# iOS. Complex stretching?

Tags: ios, autoresize, stretch, rect, stretching

I want to stretch an image using 2 stretch areas. So I need to achieve something like this:

[image]

But by default in iOS I can define one rect only.

Is it possible to solve this issue without incision into 2 separate images when each of them has only one rect?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The image you have posted is still confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, I would definitely do with 2 images. Or add a category on top of UIImage which does your job. The key is what kind of parameter will you give to the method?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing which iOS provides out of the box is (as described in this [post](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html))

```
// Image with cap insets
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16)];
```

There is no way to do what you are referring to without splitting the image, or writing a custom image rendering `UIView` subclass. You should be careful if going with the later as you will be throwing away a lot of optimisations present in `UIImageView`.